# How to have a Web Service monitor Real Time Data using .NET?

Tags: .net, web-services, real-time

I would like to know whether a Web Service can be used to monitor real time data. If so can I get any links to tutorials? I want tutorials using .NET. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your real time data comes to the Web service as requests, then sure. If you're getting your data somewhere other than from client requests, then use a Windows service. As written, your question is unanswerable. What is "real time?" What kind of data are you monitoring? More information will get you better answers.

Comment: What I mean by real time data is new applications for jobs or may be a log which is saved in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes, it is absolutely possible to do what you're asking. You could write an ASP.NET web service that has a connection to your database.

Create a timer on the page, in javascript, to call your web service at some interval and then process the results.

Here are a few tutorials to get you going. They are pretty verbose, so I hope you like to read haha.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call